# Arduino EMG with 5000 Hz Nyquist sampling

Tags: arduino, amplifier, differential-amplifier

I need to build an EMG using Arduino that can detect up to 2000 Hz (instead of just up to 250 Hz) so the sampling needs to be at least 5000 Hz (to satisfy Nyquist theorem).

I want to focus on the higher frequency sector.
But so far the circuit I found that can work with the Arduino is only 40 Hz.

https://www.olimex.com/Products/Duino/Shields/SHIELD-EKG-EMG/open-source-hardware

What open source hardware must I start to build this (1 to 2000 Hz EMG (instead of the usual 1 - 250Hz))?

Is the Arduino (like Uno) even adequate for the tasked? If not, what microcontroller is required for it?

The signal at higher frequency (like 1000 Hz) must be clear to be distinguishable.

Comment: The schematic shows a lowpass filter with a cutoff of 40 Hz.  You would want to increase that cut off frequency to at least 2000 Hz and then select a part with a sampling rate of at least 4000 Hz to use as the ADC (but I would go somewhat higher to be safe).

Answer (score 2):

> the circuit I found that can work with the Arduino is only 40 Hz.

This is because the [circuit](https://www.olimex.com/Products/Duino/Shields/SHIELD-EKG-EMG/resources/SHIELD-EKG-EMG-REV-B-SCHEMATIC.pdf) has a low pass filter stage with cutoff frequency of 40 Hz:-

[image]

You can modify this filter for a higher  cutoff frequency by reducing the capacitor values proportionally. 2 kHz / 40 Hz = 50, so dividing the value of each capacitor by 50 should produce a cutoff frequency of 2 kHz.

The rest of the EMG circuit also needs to have a bandwidth of at least 2 kHz. At a voltage gain of 10 the [INA321](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina321.pdf?ts=1662333710316&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FINA321%253Futm_source%253Dgoogle%2526utm_medium%253Dcpc%2526utm_campaign%253Dasc-null-null-GPN_EN-cpc-pf-google-wwe%2526utm_content%253DINA321%2526ds_k%253DINA321%2526DCM%253Dyes%2526gclid%253DCj0KCQjwmdGYBhDRARIsABmSEeOlV5ZaFcnSZhzApP0MqfraIFU-fNKBYMFit4lt6k7KaJ27UWAZjzMaAlyuEALw_wcB%2526gclsrc%253Daw.ds) instrumentation amp is good to over 100 kHz. At a gain of 101 the [MCP607](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/11177f.pdf) has a bandwidth of 2 kHz, which is just right.

[image]

However C8 in parallel with R12 gives this stage a low pass cutoff at ~1.6 kHz, so you should remove C8 to realize the op amp's full bandwidth.

Note that C28 and C29 have already been removed from this circuit, and R30 and R31 are zero ohm links. Therefore none of these (nonexistent) parts have any effect.

> Is the Arduino (like Uno) even adequate for the tasked?

With proper programming it should be adequate, provided the Arduino doesn't have to do any heavy post-processing. The Uno's ADC takes ~104 μs to convert a 10 bit sample. At a sample rate of 5 kHz that leaves 96 μs or ~1536 CPU cycles spare between samples.

> The signal at higher frequency (like 1000 Hz) must be clear to be
> distinguishable.

A 1 kHz tone sampled at 5 kHz should be easily distinguishable.

With wider bandwidth the noise floor will increase. However below 2 kHz the INA321's internal noise is dominated by lower frequencies, so the extra from 40 Hz to 2 kHz shouldn't be much. The biggest challenge will probably be eliminating EMI from AC mains etc.

Comment: If I build this on a breadboard, how much noise will it introduce versus soldering them solid in a pcb? Also. Do you know a company that can build the above for a fee? Thanks.

Comment: The frequencies involved are 'low', so a breadboard should be fine if sensibly laid out. Olimex might be willing to produce a customized version of their SHIELD-EKG-EMG for you if you ask them nicely. Or you could modify the design and send it to a PCB manufacturer like PCBWay, who will make the boards and install the smd components. If you just need a one-off then any competent electronics technician could modify it for you if don't have the skills to do it yourself. But why not do it yourself, and learn valuable skills as well as avoiding the hassle of building the whole thing from scratch?

Comment: If I dont use an Arduino, are there other microcontrollers that can do it? also if i increase the range 1 to 230,000 Hz instead of just 1 to 2000 Hz, can the Arduino still be adequate?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a full answer to your question but there may be some useful analysis of the BioAmp products from Upside Down Labs in my recent [article](https://www.instructables.com/EMG-With-Arduino-UNO-R4-WiFi-and-DIY-Neuroscience-/) where I look at using the Arduino UNO R4 WiFi with their kit. I looked at the hardware filtering/amplification on two of their products and how it interacts with software filtering on the humble Arduino Uno, lots of plots (calculated not measured) to look at. If you are intend or end up doing some software filtering on a microcontroller then a 500sps to 5ksps jump means 1/10th of the time to do that and that could be another limiting factor on your upper sample rate.

The hardware filtering on the [Muscle BioAmp Shield](https://store.upsidedownlabs.tech/product/muscle-bioamp-shield-v0-3/) looks compatible with your rates plus it comes in through hole kit form so would be easy to tweak if needed.

I recently did some [DMA ADC on the Pi Pico's RP2040](https://www.instructables.com/Making-a-Guitar-Tuner-and-Audio-Spectrum-Analyser-/). That's nice because you can sample up to 500ksps and easily bring the data into a pair of buffers for continuous, uninterrupted real-time processing. Two fast cores to play with, but no hardware floating point...